# Extract Data from gridview to textboxes

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I've got a gridview that I'm trying to exctract data to populate 3 textboxes... I've tried numerous ways, but I just can't get to the right way of doing this... I've built the gridview manually, thus it does not have a "editTemplate"... Can someone please direct me in the right way to do this?
This is how my gridview looks like:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" 
                                EmptyDataText="No parts has been added to the model, please add a part."
                                BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"  BorderWidth="2px" 
                                CellPadding="3" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CssClass="EditButton" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CssClass="DeleteButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC"  BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                                BorderWidth="2px" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Then this is how I've added the necessary columns to that gridview:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        MakeDataTable();
        EmptyDataString();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
    }
    ViewState["DataTable"] = dt; 

}

#region GridView

private void EmptyDataString()
{
    TemplateBuilder tmpEmptyDataTemplate = new TemplateBuilder();
    tmpEmptyDataTemplate.AppendLiteralString("No parts has been added to the model, please add a part.");
    GridView1.EmptyDataTemplate = tmpEmptyDataTemplate;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private void MakeDataTable()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Item");
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("Price P/Quantity");
}

private void AddToDataTable()
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Item"] = txtPart.Text;
    dr["Quantity"] = numQuantity.Text;
    dr["Price P/Quantity"] = txtPricePQ.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void btnAddPart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToDataTable();
    BindGrid();
    ClearNewParts();
}
#endregion
```

And these are some ways that I have tried to do this: (all are commented out as I moved on to the next way to do this.....

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  //  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
        {
            //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow].BeginEdit();
            //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow]["yourFieldName"] = newValue;
            //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow].EndEdit();
            //gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
      //  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

       // Department = ((GridViewRow(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[2].Text;
      //  txtPart.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
       // txtPart.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
       // Response.Write(gv.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text); //consider you use bound field and the column you want to show its value is the first column.
    }
```

I know I am doing something wrong on how I am trying to achieve extracting the data out of the gridview to populate the textboxes, but not sure how.... (I'm still a junior programming and basically the first time doing what I'm trying to achieve here)....

Comment: try using for loop after if finishes in your code, as i have used in my answer.

Comment: you can cache your dataTable before binding and retrieve the data using the cached dt.

Comment: Please look at my edited answer. Third Alternative

Comment: @ Freelancer, @BlackHatShadow - Will give both a try to see if it will work. problem is it's giving errors of selectedRow or Row no matter how I am trying to do this....

Comment: on my solution, you only have to cache the table then you only have to reference the id from `.SelectedKey` then get the row from the cached dt using your key. gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code>>

If Windows App>>

```
for(int i=0;i<gv.Rows.Count;i++)
{
       id=gv.selectedRows[i].cells[0][0].value.toString();
       name=gv.selectedRows[i].cells[0][0].value.toString();
}
```

Otherwise

You can get selected rows from gridview by this.

If you want without selection then,

```
for(int i=0;i<gv.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
           id=gv.Rows[i].cells[0][0].value.toString();
           name=gv.Rows[i].cells[0][0].value.toString();
    }
```

Third Alternative>>

```
     if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
            {
                //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow].BeginEdit();
                //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow]["yourFieldName"] = newValue;
                //dataTable.Rows[GridView1.SelectedRow].EndEdit();
                //gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
          //  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    for(int i=0;i<GridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
            Department = ((GridViewRow(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[2].Text;
            txtPart.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow[i][0].Cells[1].Text;
           txtPart.Text = GridView1.Rows[i][0].Cells[2].Text;
           Response.Write(gv.Rows[i][0].Cells[0].Text); //consider you use bound field and the column you want to show its value is the first column.
        }
}
```

Further you can set these variables to textboxes.

Or directly also you can set it.

Try Out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the I'm gettin an error of "System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'selectedRows' and no extension method 'selectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"... I've had this error on one of the methods that I tried, but not sure how to fix it?

Comment: yes, and then I get an error that says: "System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" ...trying to search for a solution for this, but nothing helpfull... can it be that the control is a gridview and then a datatable is used to add the necessary columns and rows?